# HTTP Post request not executing to success or error

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm having trouble with my HTTP post request in Cloud Code and for some reason it's not actually getting to the success or error messages. It will log out the JSON variable that I've encoded, but seems to not execute the HTTP request at all. Any ideas on what my issue is?

```
Parse.Cloud.job("getUsers", function(request, status) {
  // Query to get users
    var users = Parse.Object.extend("_User");
    var query = new Parse.Query(users);
    var t = 0;
    query.notEqualTo("mkUsername", "");
    query.notEqualTo("mkPassword", "");
    query.equalTo("canUseMK", "1");
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
                var object = results[i];
                var requestVariables = { mkUsername: object.get("mkUsername"), mkPassword:object.get("mkPassword"), userID: object.id };
                var requestJsonString = JSON.stringify(requestVariables);
                console.log(requestJsonString);
                Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://url.com/api_trial.php',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                        'authKey' : 'XXXXXXXXXX'
                    },
                    body:requestJsonString,
                    success: function(httpResponse) {
                        ++t;
                        console.log(httpResponse.text);
                        response.success(httpResponse.text);
                        status.message("User "+ i + " Response " + httpResponse.status);
                    },
                    error: function(httpResponse) {
                        //get the status code
                        if (httpResponse.status == 400) {
                            console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
                            response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
                        }
                        else if (httpResponse.status == 401) {
                            console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
                            response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
                        }
                        else if (httpResponse.status == 409) {
                            console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
                            response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
                        } else {
                            console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
                            response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            status.success("Synced "+ i + " Users Data");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            status.error("Had query issue: " + error);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP request gets executed asynchronously but you call `status.success` directly after starting the HTTP request which might not have finished.

This will make the job return as if it was done and any running HTTP request should be terminated resulting in the behavior you see. Move the call of `status.success` into the success function of your request and it should be fine.